# SPAMASSASSIN : How to enable spamassassin for my email?

Tags: 14.04, email

By following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-spamassassin-on-ubuntu-12-04), I have installed 'spamassassin' in my ubuntu 14.04, but I have no idea how to enable it for my email id,
when I run the following comment,

```
nano /etc/default/spamassassin
```

I got as,

[image]

And I am stuck in here, I tried

```
^G
^R
^X
```

but noting happening...

[image]

Please anyone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to get out of that `nano` editor.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - to save the changes made on that file.

Comment: thank you.. could you help me how to enable spammassassin with my email ?

Comment: check the spelling. it's `nano /etc/default/spamassassin` it's not `/etc/default/spammassin`

Comment: you have to enter the file path correctly otherwise an empty file would appear like in the above screenshot.

Comment: I tried that too... i can't find the file

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /etc/default/spamassassin`